# pandas groupby with both "mean" and list of rows

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with dates, names and a numerical score. I'm trying to use pd.groupby to create a new df containing the average of the numerical over an hourly interval but also the list of all them names appearing in that hour:

What I have:

| Dates | Name | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hour 1 | A | 5 |
| Hour 2 | B | 2 |
| Hour 2 | C | 6 |
| Hour 2 | D | 4 |

What I want:

| Hours | Name | Score (Avg) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5 |
| 2 | [B,C,D] | 4 |

I know I can create each of them separately with

```py
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="date",freq='60min')]).agg("mean")
```

or
use the `.apply(list)` to get the names in lists

But I would like to do both. Any ideas? the data might be pretty big so preferably the solution is somewhat fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need lists for each values, also one element lists use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with names aggregations:

```
df1 = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="date",freq='60min')])
         .agg(Name = ("Name",list), Avg = ("Score","mean")))
```

Or:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(df["date"].dt.hour)
         .agg(Name = ("Name",list), Avg = ("Score","mean")))


print (df1)
           Name  Avg
date                
1           [A]    5
2     [B, C, D]    4
```

If need scalar for one element lists need custom function:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(df["date"].dt.hour)
        .agg(Name = ("Name",lambda x: list(x) if len(x)>1 else x), Avg = ("Score","mean")))
print (df1)
           Name  Avg
date                
1             A    5
2     [B, C, D]    4
```

Last for `Hours` column use:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index().rename(columns={"date":"Hours"})
```